# Is there an exponential bound for $(1+p)^{-n}$ when $p$ is small?

Tags: probability, inequality

Is there an exponential upper bound for $(1+p)^{-n}$ when $0<p<1$? Similarly a exponential lower bound for $(1+p)^n$ will also be good.  Do you know of any resources where one can pick up bounds as such quickly? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $p$ in $(0,1)$. Since $p-\frac12p^2\lt\log(1+p)\lt p$,
$$
\mathrm e^{np(1-p/2)}\lt(1+p)^n\lt\mathrm e^{np}.
$$
Likewise, $\log(1-p)\lt-p$ and
$$
-\log(1-p)=\sum_{k\geqslant1}\frac{p^k}k\lt p+\frac{p^2}2\sum_{k\geqslant0}p^k=p\frac{1-p/2}{1-p},
$$
hence
$$
\mathrm e^{-np(1-p/2)/(1-p)}\lt(1-p)^n\lt\mathrm e^{-np}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

When $np \ll 1, (1\pm p)^n \approx 1 \pm np$ with the accuracy improving as $np$ gets smaller.  The error is of order $\frac {(np)^2}2$.  When you say exponential bound, do you want less than exponential growth?  It certainly doesn't fall exponentially

Comment: I'm thinking more along the lines of this: we know that $(1+p)^n < e^{pn}$, for instance. And in fact $(1-p)^{-n}= e^{-n log(1+p)}$, so maybe after expanding $log(1+p)$ I can get an 'exponential' upper bound?

Comment: @Heidi:  for $(1+p)^n$ that is already an exponential bound as $n \to infty$, as is $(1-p)^n$